# Minimal prerequisite to understand De Rham Cohomology

Tags: soft-question, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, de-rham-cohomology

To understand the concept of De Rham Cohomology formally, what is the minimum background required?

That is, what are the critical concepts? For example, a list might be something like: tangent bundle, cotangent bundle, differential forms, integration on manifolds

I have a somewhat short amount of time to write an expository paper on De Rham Cohomology for a seminar course, and I want to get a feel for the necessary prerequisite components.

Comment: Did you try [From Calculus to cohomology](https://www.amazon.com/Calculus-Cohomology-Rham-Characteristic-Classes/dp/0521589568)? The essential concept is just advanced calculus, at least if you care only about open set in $\mathbb R^n$. On the other hand, if the audience are comfortable with manifold (just the definition), then Bott and Tu is a much better choice.

Comment: @JohnMa the audience will definitely be ok with topological manifolds. I will look at both. Thank you

Comment: I will say that the minimum background to understand the concept is: Differentiable manifolds, tangent and cotangent bundles, differential forms and the exterior derivative, and the difference between closed and exact forms. To just understand the concept you do not need to know about integration on manifolds.

Answer (score 1):

You've made a pretty good start with your list.

For the **definition** of deRham cohomology, you need the cochain complex of differential forms
$$
\cdots\rightarrow\Omega^n\xrightarrow{d}\Omega^{n+1}\xrightarrow{d}\cdots
$$
However, the definition of the deRham groups won't make a heck of a lot of sense unless your audience already possesses some familiarity with homology theory, say the singular homology and cohomology groups.

For the **statement** of deRham's theorem, and why it "makes sense", you need singular cohomology, the pairing $(\omega,c)\mapsto \int_c\omega$ (i.e., integration over chains), and Stokes' theorem.

There are two well-known **proofs** of deRham's theorem. deRham's original proof is presented in the book by Singer and Thorpe *Lecture Notes on Elementary Topology and Geometry*. Later on Weil gave another proof; Weil's proof fits in better with modern concepts (e.g., homological algebra, sheaves). Sternberg had a very nice set of slides on this, but they don't seem to be available on the web any more.